# protocol only can be use as generic

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm trying to use protocol in my class here is the code

```
public protocol Channel {

 typealias CallBackType
 func onResponse(responseDic: NSDictionary)
 func onRequest(responseDic: NSDictionary)
 func onBroadcast(responseDic: NSDictionary)
 func request(var messageDic: [String:String]) -> Promise<Any>
 func broadcast(var messageDic:[String:AnyObject])
 func listen(messageDic:[String: AnyObject], callback:CallBackType)
}
```

Then I have other class where I create the class that use my protocol

```
public  class SocketManager {
  var systemChannel:SystemChannel?
public var socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: hostUrl, options: ["log":      false,
    "reconnects": true,
    "reconnectAttempts": 5,
    "reconnectWait": 5,
    "connectParams": ["token":tokenSDK]])

public func start_socket() -> Promise<Bool> {
 systemChannel = SystemChannel(socket: self.socket)
}

public func getChannel(typeChannel:SOCKET_CHANNELS) -> Channel{
    switch typeChannel{
        case .SYSTEM:
            return  systemChannel!
        default:
            return systemChannel!
    }
}
}
```

Here is the SystemChannel class

```
public  class SystemChannel: Channel {
 public typealias CallBackType = [String: AnyObject] -> Void
}
```

But I get compile error on the getChannel method  `Protocol 'Channel' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`